# windows batch errorlevel with if

Tags: windows, batch-file, errorlevel

In the below script even if errorlevel is 0, Its going to if condition "if errorlevel 1"

```
@echo off
if exist servers.txt goto :continue
echo servers.txt file is missing
exit

:continue    
set instance=%username:~2%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (servers.txt) do (
  pushd \\%%i\D$\%instance%\Hyperion\oracle_common 2>nul  
  if not errorlevel 1 (  
    echo %%i
    echo **********************************
    set ORACLE_HOME=!CD!
    echo ORACLE_HOME is !ORACLE_HOME!
    D:
    FOR /D /r D:\%instance%\Hyperion %%a in ("jdk160_*") DO CD %%a
    set JAVA_HOME=!CD!
    echo JAVA_HOME is !JAVA_HOME!
    echo D:\%instance%\Hyperion\oracle_common\oui\bin\setup.exe -jreLoc !JAVA_HOME! -silent -attachHome ORACLE_HOME=!ORACLE_HOME! ORACLE_HOME_NAME="REMOTE_EPM"
    D:\%instance%\Hyperion\oracle_common\oui\bin\setup.exe -jreLoc !JAVA_HOME! -silent -attachHome ORACLE_HOME=!ORACLE_HOME! ORACLE_HOME_NAME=REMOTE_EPM
    echo error code is:%errorlevel%
    if errorlevel 2 (
        echo unable to attach remote server %%i ORACLE_HOME to inventory
        pause
        exit
    )
    cd D:\%instance%\Hyperion\oracle_common\OPatch
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo Failed to locate OPatch location D:\%instance%\Hyperion\oracle_common\OPatch
        pause
        exit
    )
    echo current: !CD!
    opatch.bat lsinv | find "applied on"
    D:\%instance%\Hyperion\oracle_common\oui\bin\setup.exe -jreLoc !JAVA_HOME! -silent -detachHome ORACLE_HOME=!ORACLE_HOME! ORACLE_HOME_NAME="REMOTE_EPM"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo Error: unable to detach remote server %%i ORACLE_HOME from inventory
        pause
        exit
    )
    popd
    pause
  ) else (
    echo ORACLE_HOME is Not found: \\%%~i\D$\%instance%\Hyperion\oracle_common
  )
  pause
)
endlocal
```

---

Output is:

```
vmhodwbrep9.oracleoutsourcing.com
**********************************
ORACLE_HOME is Y:\pwbre7\Hyperion\oracle_common
JAVA_HOME is D:\pwbre7\Hyperion\jdk160_35
D:\pwbre7\Hyperion\oracle_common\oui\bin\setup.exe -jreLoc D:\pwbre7\Hyperion\jdk160_35 -silent -attachHome ORACLE_HOME=Y:\pwbre7\Hyperion\oracle_common ORACLE_HOME_NAME="REMOTE_EP
M"
error code is:0
unable to attach remote server vmhodwbrep9.oracleoutsourcing.com ORACLE_HOME to inventory
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Am I wrong or is your `if errorlevel 1` inside `if not errorlevel 1`?

Comment: @ DevilsAdvocate- It is under if not errorlevel 1 only, in case if you say that is not supported, then there is another scenario if we replace oracle_common with EPMSystem11R1 in the script it worked[i.e., another folder]. Technically speaking both[ EPMSystem11R1 &oracle_common ]returning same errorlevel as 0

Answer (score 2):

Unless command extensions are enabled, you cannot easily access `ERRORLEVEL` in an echo statement.

Also keep in mind that you must check your conditions in reverse because...:

```
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ....
```

checks to see if ERRORLEVEL is greater than or equal to one.  So, a series of tests would be:

```
 IF ERRORLEVEL 5 ....
 IF ERRORLEVEL 4 ....
 IF ERRORLEVEL 3 ....
 IF ERRORLEVEL 2 ....
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ....
```

Finally, recognize that in an `IF` statement, `%errorlevel% is *not* the same as`ERRORLEVEL`.  You don't try it this way, but another answer does.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
echo error code is:%errorlevel%
if errorlevel 2 (
```

to

```
call echo error code is:%%errorlevel%%
if errorlevel 2 (
```

OR, preferably since you have invoked `delayedexpansion`,

```
echo error code is:!errorlevel!
if errorlevel 2 (
```

With your current code, the entirity from

if not errorlevel 1 (

to the single <kbd>)</kbd> before the `endlocal` line is one `block statement`.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, since the block starts with

```
if not errorlevel 1 (
```

then `%errorlevel%` will be replaced by the value of `errorlevel` at the time the `if` is encountered, that is `0`, so your `echo` will be replaced by `echo error code is:0`

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

**note that last statement**

> CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

So your `errorlevel` would now be displayed correctly, but would be reset to `0` by the `call`.